# IIS7.5 WCF Service - HTTP Error 401.3 (Even after adding IIS_IUSRS)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, iis-7

We have website that uses "NT Authority\Network Service".

```
Response.Write(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
```

The website uses a WCF Service that is hosted in IIS 7.5. We are getting the following error when we browse the service – “**HTTP Error 401.3 – Unauthorized**. You do not have permissions to view this directory or page because of the access control list (ACL) configuration or encryption settings for this resource on the Web Server.”

Note: We have already granted Read rights to **IIS_IUSRS** and **IUSR**  on the folders.

Any idea, how we can resolve this error?

The application pool for the service has following details

.NET Framework version: .NET Framework v4.0.30319

Managed Pipeline mode: Classic

The Application for the service has the following configuration

•   **Anonymous Authentication**: Enabled

•   Windows Authentication: Disabled

•   ASP.NET impersonation: Disabled

•   Forms Authentication: Disabled

Comment: What is the identity of the application pool?

Answer (score 6):

Most likely it is this (in order of most likely to least):
Besides enabling Anonymous Authentication for the web site, edit Anonymous Authentication (by right clicking) and change it from a Specific User to Application pool identity.

OR

Computer Management (right click on my computer and select Manage) --> Local Users and Groups --> Users --> Select IUSR_MACHINENAME (ie,IUSR_TOMATO-CLOWNFIS) --> Right click Properties --> Make sure it is a member of IIS_WPG and users and not Guests.

OR

On Your IIS Server -> Assign a USER NAME and PASSWORD to anonymous login which has full read rights on the folder or physical path of resources.
 Hope this resolves the issue.